# refetch or rerender event for eventAfterAllRender fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

im using eventAfterAllRender in displaying my event in month view because i need to count the events per day. but im unable to refetch or rerender after adding new events. please help.

This is my sample code of displaying.

```
 eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
        $(element).each(function () { 
            $(this).attr('date-num', event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); 
        });
    },
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
        for( cDay = view.start.clone(); cDay.isBefore(view.end) ; cDay.add(1, 'day') ){
            var dateNum = cDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var dayEl = $('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateNum + '"]');
            var eventCount = $('.fc-event[date-num="' + dateNum + '"]').length;
            if(eventCount){
                var html = '<span class="event-count">' + 
                            '<i>' +
                            eventCount + 
                            '</i>' +
                            ' Events' +
                            '</span>';

                dayEl.append(html);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: none of this code relates to adding new events or refetching events. Also what does "unable to" mean, exactly? You mean you don't know how to do that, or you get an error when you try it, or something else? Your question is unclear and I think it is also missing some relevant code.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for the late reply. I decided not to worry about it anymore. But i have another more serious problem. Please help me sir. This is the link for the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576674/fullcalendar-ajax-call-fired-multiple-times-without-reloading-page