# Fullcalendar AJAX call fired multiple times without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

When I click a day in month view, a modal will pop-up.

Inside that modal is a button for adding a new event. When I click that, another modal will pop-up for the Add Event form.

The problem is when I frequently open/close the first modal and try to add an event after that without reloading the page, the AJAX call fires multiple times even if I click the submit only once. Sometimes it multiplies up to 7 times.

I don't know what the problem is.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'today',
          center: 'prev title next',
          right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventOrder: 'start',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        events: 'getEvents.php',
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            var today = new Date();
            var startString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var endString = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            $(element).each(function () { 
              $(this).attr('date-num', event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); 
            });
        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
          for( cDay = view.start.clone(); cDay.isBefore(view.end) ; cDay.add(1, 'day') ){
            var dateNum = cDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var dayEl = $('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateNum + '"]');
            var eventCount = $('.fc-event[date-num="' + dateNum + '"]').length;
            if(eventCount){
              var html = '<span class="event-count">' + 
                        '<i>' +
                        eventCount + 
                        '</i>' +
                        ' Events' +
                        '</span>';

              dayEl.append(html);
            }
          }
        },
        dayClick: function(start, end, event) {
          var st = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
          var en = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

          function fetch_data() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "view-data.php",
              data: 'action=view&start=' + st + '&end=' + en,
              method: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                $('#view-me').html(data);
                $('#view-data').modal('show');
              }
            });
          }

          fetch_data();

          $(document).on('click', '.add-me', function() {
            $('#start').val(moment($(this).data('start')).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#end').val(moment($(this).data('end')).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');

            $('#myFormAdd').on('submit', function(e) { // add event submit
              e.preventDefault();
              doAdd(); // send to form submit function
            });

            function doAdd() { // add event
              var title = $('#title').val();
              var start = $('#start').val();
              var end = $('#end').val();

              $.ajax({
                url: 'addEvent.php',
                data: 'action=add&title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                  $('#ModalAdd').modal('hide');
                  fetch_data();
                  calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      );
```

My PHP Code: view-data.php

```
 if($_POST['action'] == "view") // view event dayClick
{ 
 $start = $_POST['start'];
 $end = $_POST['end'];
 ?>

  //Add new button
  <button title="add new here" class="add-me" data-start="<?php echo $start; ?>" 
  data-end="<?php echo $end; ?>" rel="dialog" >ADD</button>

<?php 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' OR end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {
  ?>

  <span style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></span>

  <?php
  }
  } else {
     echo "<span>No event</span>";
  }
  }   
  ?>
```

Comment: your code is half, not proper so please create js fiddle so can understand error

Comment: @BhumiShah i've edited my code and iclude all of it.

Comment: your code is still not proper you have written $(document).on('click', '.add-me', function() { with calender?

Comment: @BhumiShah but that is all my code. yeah. what should i do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently inside your dayClick event handler you've got code to add all your other event handlers, and also defined some functions. This is not a good thing to do, because it means that every time a user clicks on a day, this code will run and keep adding more and more event handlers to your page. Adding an event handler does not overwrite previously added handlers, it just keeps adding more. Then every time the event you add the handler to is triggered, it executes *all* the event handlers attached to it, simultaneously.

This explains why sometimes you see your ajax calls run again and again - it will be in the cases where you've clicked on a day (or different days) more than once already.

You need to make sure you event handling code only ever runs *once*, and your functions are only ever declared once. To do this, move all that code outside your calendar config. You then also need to allow some parameters to be passed to the fetch_data function, so that it knows what to fetch without relying on closure scope:

So, in your fullCalendar code:

```
dayClick: function(start, end, event) {
  fetch_data(start, end);
}
```

That's it, that's all you need inside the calendar config.

Then, *outside* your calendar config:

```
function fetch_data(start, end) {
  var st = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  var en = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  $.ajax({
    url: "view-data.php",
    data: 'action=view&start=' + st + '&end=' + en,
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#view-me').html(data);
      $('#view-data').modal('show');
    }
  });
}


$(document).on('click', '.add-me', function() {
  $('#start').val(moment($(this).data('start')).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
  $('#end').val(moment($(this).data('end')).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
  $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
});

$(document).on("submit", '#myFormAdd', function(e) { // add event submit
  e.preventDefault();
  doAdd(); // send to form submit function
});

function doAdd() { // add event
  var title = $('#title').val();
  var start = $('#start').val();
  var end = $('#end').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'addEvent.php',
    data: 'action=add&title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
      $('#ModalAdd').modal('hide');
      //fetch_data(); //it's not clear why you would need to do this here, since you've just hidden the modal which is populates! Pretty sure you don't need it, so I've commented it out
      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm almost there. My only problem now is how can i update the data inside the modal `$('#view-data').modal('show');` from the function fetch_data after ajax success for add new event. Because i also displayed there in the modal `dayClick` all the events per day. The `fetch_data();` you commented is my way of refetching the data inside modal. So whenever i add new event, the event will automatically displayed in the modal at the same time in the calendar.

Comment: Are these events not already shown on the main calendar display? Why not just close that modal? The user can click the day again if they want to see detail, but they already know what's there because they just typed it a moment before. Probably they want to do something else now.

Comment: if you really want to update the modal though, you can just uncomment that line and change it to fetch_data(moment(start), moment(end)); so that the correct start and end dates are supplied again...assuming those haven't been changed by the user? Or find another way to get the correct dates to be available in that function, e.g. maybe using data properties like you did for the add-me button.

Comment: Great solution! I had the same problem and now after reading it i understand the problem and could fix it! thnx for answer

Answer (score 3):

Move the `$(document).on('click', '.add-me', function(){` out of the `dayClick` callback

Every time you click on  a day you are adding a new click event listener for the `add-me`

So clicking on 3 days would add 3 listeners and then a click on `add-me` will run the event handler ( and ajax) 3 times

Comment: i put the `$(document).on('click', '.add-me', function(){` inside the `dayClick` so i can refetch the modal after ajax success. How can i refetch the data inside the modal dayClick if i move it out? Please help.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You have delegated it to `document` which always exists